# "I just wanted to check" with before

Tags: tense

When you use the phrase "I just wanted to check" with the word "before," do you usually use present tense or past simple?

In the example below, I'm trying to say thank you after receiving an answer to a question.

> I just wanted to check if this outfit is acceptable before I go/went to the party.

If I'm still not at the party, which tense should I use?

Answer (score 2):

In your example sentence, you can use "go" if you have not yet gone to the party.

You could use "went" either before going, or after going.

As a side note, I would probably prefer to say "I just wanted to check *whether*..." rather than "I just wanted to check *if*..." That's a personal preference. I think many people would agree with me, but I have definitely heard it both ways.

Comment: Actually, it seems that really *is* just personal preference. But because I happen to lean the other way, I went to the trouble of checking Google Books. [I just wanted to check **whether**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+just+wanted+to+check+whether%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):81 hits; [I just wanted to check **if**](https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22I+just+wanted+to+check+if%22&btnG=Search+Books&tbm=bks&tbo=1):1380 hits. I base *my* preference on the fact that *whether* seems a bit more "formal" to me, but OP's words before it here sound *just* (!) a bit casual/informal.

Answer (score 0):

I would use the Simple Present.

> I just wanted to check if this outfit is acceptable before I go to the party.

As alternative, I would use the gerund.

> I just wanted to check if this outfit is acceptable before going to the party.

Comment: kiam, are you sure "going" is gerund there. As far as I know it may be a present participle, no?

Comment: Nope, it's a gerund: A form that is derived from a verb but that functions as a noun. In fact, [going](http://oald8.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/dictionary/going) is a noun.

Comment: kiam, but how does this "gerund" work? Rougly, do you think it is something like "prima di andare al party"? I thought it was "prima di essere andante al party", ecco why I said "present participle".

Comment: In Italian, it would be _prima di andare al party_. _Andando_ is never used as noun, in Italian, and _andante_ is used for who is doing the action, not the action.